# FATAL:terminating connection due to the administrator command

Tags: postgresql

Every day the application end they scheduling the job which is triggering early morning,  here the issue that , some times queries is killed automatically,  no one is killed the sessions even application team and DBA  also not killed the session's,  it happening very rare causes.

Any one can help me on it

Need any one help to solve this issue

Comment: "due to the administrator command" Somebody did this, it's not something the database does by itself. Check the logfiles.

Comment: The PostgreSQL server's log file should give you at least some clue as to why it is happening.